# What's the use of a confirm box if it doesn't appear until after code behind completes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-server, code-behind, confirm

I am trying to validate a textbox value with a javascript Confirm message. If the user clicks OK then I want the textbox value added to a listbox, but if the user clicks cancel, I want to clear the textbox and not add it to the list. This is very simple to do in a desktop application but I am trying to create a web application and I have been struggling with this for weeks now.

In the textbox.textchanged event, I have this code, which firsts checks to make sure the value is not already in the list (PublicCalls.ListContainsIndex), then searches a table to make sure the value isn't already flagged as Counted (brlCounted). If it has already been counted, the user should get a prompt asking if he wants to continue re-counting that value or skip it:

```
    Protected Sub txtBrlKey_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBrlKey.TextChanged
    Dim tmpBarrels As New cBarrels

    Try
        With Me
            If Trim(.txtBrlKey.Text) <> "" Then
                If Not PublicCalls.ListContainsIndex(Me, .lstBarrels, .txtBrlKey.Text) > -1 Then
                    If Me.Title = "frmBarrelMoves" And (PublicCalls.gPhysicalInventory Or PublicCalls.gCycleCount) Then ' called from the Physical Inventory or Cycle Count form (frmBarremMoves)
                        tmpBarrels = tmpBarrels.Search(Me, "spa_Barrel_Select '" & .txtBrlKey.Text & "'")
                        If LCase(tmpBarrels.item(1).BrlCounted) = LCase("Y") Then
                            If PublicCalls.MsgBoxConfirm(Me, "This Barrel ID has already been counted. Continue?") = False Then
                                txtBrlKey.Text = "" ' clear the control 
                            Else
                                gBarrelEntered = True
                                UpdateBarrelList("I", .txtBrlKey.Text) ' add the barrel to the barrel list
                                gBarrelEntered = False

                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With

        tmpBarrels = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception
        PublicCalls.DisplayBblErrors(Me, ex, Nothing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The code for MsgBoxConfirm looks like this:

```
    Public Shared Function MsgBoxConfirm(thePage As Page, Message As String) As Boolean
    Dim HiddenConfirmResponse As HiddenField = CType(thePage.Master.FindControl("txtConfirmResponse"), HiddenField)

    MsgBoxConfirm = False
    HiddenConfirmResponse.Value = ""

    ' somehow this function needs to return true or false depending on if the user clicked OK or Cancel
    ' the problem is that ConfirmBox fires after the server side code finishes, which is too late to capture the OK or Cancel response here

    Try
        thePage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(thePage.[GetType](), "ConfirmBox", (Convert.ToString("ConfirmBox('") & Message) + "');", True)

        If HiddenConfirmResponse.Value = "OK" Then
            MsgBoxConfirm = True
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        PublicCalls.DisplayBblErrors(thePage, ex, Nothing)
    End Try

End Function
```

The javascript (in Site.Master header) looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ConfirmBox(message) {

            var Answer = confirm(message);

            if (Answer) {

                document.getElementById('<%=txtConfirmResponse.ClientID%>').value = "OK";

            } else {

                document.getElementById('<%=txtConfirmResponse.ClientID%>').value = "Cancel";
            }
        }
</script>
```

And the hidden txtConfirmResponse is defined in the body:

```
            <asp:HiddenField ID="txtConfirmResponse" runat="server" />
```

By the time the confirm box shows up, the Code Behind has already moved on and since the MsgBoxConfirm returns false by default, the value is never added to the list. If I change the default to True, then the value is always added to the list no matter what. I have searched and searched and the consensus is that the separation between the client side code and server side code is the cause and that there is no way for me to display the confirm box when I need it -- before the value is added to the list. If that is the case, then I don't see how the confirm box could ever be useful. I see responses that say, "do it a different way" but how? Can anyone provide a clear example of how I need to change this code to make it work? I have tried the Ajax ModalPopupExtender but it makes no difference on when the confirm box is shown.

Very frustrated. Thanks for any help you can provide.
Gina

Comment: have you tried using AJAX?

Comment: Yes, I tried the ModalPopupExtender but it made no difference on when the confirm box showed up -- always too late.